# Select Column Value if exist in another table other vise ignore in sum in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Table `JobMaster`:

```
JobID   |  PLID  |  SetupTime  |
|1      |    1    |     10     |
|2      |    2    |     20     |
|2      |    3    |            |
|3      |    1    |     05     |
|3      |    3    |     12     |
```

Table `OpertaionMaster`:

```
|PLID | SetupTime              |
|  1  |   12                   |
|  2  |   15                   |
|  3  |   20                   |
```

Outupt contains

Table JobMaster

```
JobID  |   Productivity  |
|1     |     12     |
|2     |     15     |
|3     |     32     |
```

Need the addition of Setup Time in OperationMaster if the SetupTime in JobMaster
is not present then it should ignore the setupTime value in addition

Please help me out

THanks in advance

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: Can you add some more sample table data, and adjust the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it a simple `INNER JOIN` and `WHERE jm.SetupTime IS NOT NULL`?

```
SELECT jm.JobID, jm.SetupTime AS Productivity 
FROM JobMaster jm 
INNER JOIN OpertaionMaster om
    ON jm.PLID = om.PLID 
WHERE jm.SetupTime IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: i have to take the sum of setup Time from Operation Master When the Setup Time in JobMaster is not null.  Please help me

Comment: @Swap: where in your output  do you sum values?

Comment: Sir i have updated the table records and output. You may get it now

Answer (score 0):

`Join` the two tables together, do a `GROUP BY` and SUM for each jobid:

```
select j.jobid, sum(o.SetupTime)
from JobMaster as j
  join OpertaionMaster as o on j.PLID = o.PLID
group by j.jobid
```

If you also want to return jobid's without any hours, do `LEFT JOIN` instead of just `JOIN`.

Comment: Sir as per your query the Setuptime for JobId gives me 35. But as there is not Setuptime in JobMaster for second record it will not add the SetuptTime of PL id 3. So i want the result as 15 for JobId 2

Comment: @Swap, sorry, didn't read carefully enough. Can you describe for each jobid how to get the Productivity values 12, 15, 32 respectively?